# Cannot convert value of type 'User?' to expected argument type 'User!' error in Firebase sign up function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I recently updated a Swift 2.0 project to Swift 3.0, and now I have this error with my Firebase signUp function (the code definitely worked before).

```
func signUp(_ email: String, username: String, password: String, data: Data!) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error == nil {

            // error here
            self.setUserInfo(user, username: username, password: password, data: data)
        }else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```

I am very grateful for any assistance with this.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Let us see your `setUserInfo()` method. `user` from the completion handler is Optional so if your method takes `User` as a parameter and you pass optional `User?` it wouldn't compile.

Comment: fileprivate func setUserInfo(_ user: User!, username: String, password: String, data: Data!){

Comment: That's your issue. Change `setUserInfo(_ user: User!...)` to `setUserInfo(_ user: User?...)` and unwrap the `User?` object in the method

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I made the change, but strangely the error is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.emailtextfield.text!, password: self.passwordtextfield.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
          if let fireBaseError = error {
                self.emailerror.isHidden = false
                self.errorlabel.text = "\(fireBaseError.localizedDescription)"
                return


         }
})
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

createUser's completion is now called with two optional parameters: `user` and `error`. While it's likely true that confirming `error == nil` necessarily means `user != nil`, Swift doesn't know that.

I can think of three good ways to change that `User?` into a `User`:

```
// What you have:
self.setUserInfo(user, username: username, password: password, data: data)

// Method 1: !
self.setUserInfo(user!, username: username, password: password, data: data)

// Method 2: if let
if let user = user {
    self.setUserInfo(user, username: username, password: password, data: data)
}

// Method 3: guard let
guard let user = user else {
    NSLog(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No user and no error. Weird.")
    return
}
self.setUserInfo(user, username: username, password: password, data: data)
```

In your situation I'd use Method 1. In a situation where you're going to use `user` again and again, I'd use method 2 or method 3, depending on whether I wanted the `user == nil` case to be inside another layer of indentation, or for the `user != nil` case to be.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just tried these; the first two methods threw the same error at the same line, and the third resulted in a new error: "Value 'user' was defined but never used; consider replacing with boolean test".

Comment: For method 1 and method 2, I'm assuming you'll start with:

    if let error = error {
      NSLog(error)
      return
    }

For method 3, I think you might have done something differently from what I posted, since `user` is used immediately after the `guard` block.

Incidentally, check out https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330 to learn more about Optionals. Just Google [swift optional] to learn more.